# Ionic Android default build.gradle settings

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, cordova-plugins

In platforms/android/build.gradle I have the following by default

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
```

Due to some plugins, I need to upgrade the default version, min version and everything else to:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.0" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=21 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change these default values without changing this file from /platforms, because this file gets removed every single time I do platforms remove / add ?

In config.xml I have this:

```
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
        <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="30" />
```

And also I have added inside the app level folder this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        supportLibVersion = “29.0.0”
}
```

But it does not seem to work, during the build I still get this error:

```
AAPT: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have below code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <activity android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Then Remove **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** from this because it's available from 29.0